# FileNotFoundError: fbs could not find executable 'makensis'. Please install NSIS and add its installation directory to your PATH envir onment variable

Tags: nsis, fbs

I wanted to create an installer for my exe programm (with fbs). Then I saw that I need to install **NSIS** (Error: FileNotFoundError: fbs could not find executable 'makensis'. Please install NSIS and add its installation directory to your PATH envir
onment variable). I did install NSIS. After that, I got the same error. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Add your NSIS directory into your environment variable. For example mine was C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS and restart your powershell.

Answer (score 0):

NSIS does not automatically add itself to %Path% when you install it. If fbs cannot detect NSIS then I suppose you have to manually update the path variable yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hi ckeck the location where NSIS software installed.

mine C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS

`when i try to uninstall it's showing correct file location then i am adding that file location to path user variabels`

Thanks,

ANR S

Answer (score 0):

Try to install "HM NIS Edit", you can choose your makensis.exe following NSIS -> Configuration.

[image]